# Claim: $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} ne^{-nx}$ converges uniformly on $[r,\infty), r>0.$

Tags: real-analysis

I tried to prove using the Weierstrass M-test to no avail. Could anyone advise on how to find the suitable upper bound for $ne^{-nx} ?$ Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your series does not converge uniformly on $[0, +\infty)$. But on $[r, +\infty)$ with $r > 0$ you can choose $ne^{-nr}$ as an upper bound.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have made a typo error. The domain is $[r,\infty), r >0. $

Comment: Thank you. But how I establish the convergence of $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} ne^{-nr} ?$

Comment: Using $e^{nr} = 1 + nr + \dfrac{n^2r^2}{2} + \dfrac{n^3r^3}{3!} + \ldots > \dfrac{n^3r^3}{3!}$, for instance.

Comment: Thank you! I think it might be easier to establish the convergence by ratio test:)